# xib views in Xcode 5 not visible in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a project in Xcode 5 that I'm migrating to Xcode 7. I have an array of custom UIViewControllers that come with XIBs. I take each object in the array and pass it through, like this

```
- (void) createViewForObject:(NSObject *)object
{

if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]])
    {
        CustomViewController *cvc = (CustomViewController*)object;

        //If I create a view controller from within the function, 
        //it successfully adds, as demonstrated below. 
        //But I'm not able to add the view of the object 
        //that was passed in from outside
        OtherCustomViewController *otherCvc = //initialization here

        UITableViewCell* cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomViewControllerCell"];
       [cvc.view frameResizeToHeight:[gtf getHeight]];
       [cvc.view frameMoveToPosition:CGPointMake(340, 0)];

       cell.frame=cvc.view.frame;
       otherCvc.view.frame = cvc.view.frame;
       [cell frameResizeToHeight:MAX(MAX(50, textSize.height+10),cell.frame.size.height)+11]; //just a resizing helper method

           //This is code that successfully adds the other custom view controller that was created within this method to the cell, but I want to use the other custom view controller (the one that was passed in from outside) so I can keep references to certain properties.
//        [cell addSubview:otherCvc.view];
//        [self addChildViewController:otherCvc];
//        [otherCvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        //This is the code that doesn't work that I want to work
       [self addChildViewController:cvc];
       cvc.view.frame = cell.frame;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:cvc.view];
       [cvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

     //I'm also able to add the custom view that was passed in from outside directly to the main view with the code below, so the views do exist. 
     //They're just not getting added to the cell.

     //[self.view addSubview:cvc.view];


    }
 }
```

I'm able to access all the properties of this custom view controller, but it won't let me add the view as a subview to the cell, even though it did allow this in Xcode 5. (the Xcode 5 was post ARC, BTW). What's also interesting is that I'm able to add the view controller subviews to the main view (to self.view)

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code you posted.  I'm assuming you're just doing an addSubview:cvc.  Can you post the code where you're adding cvc as well as any errors you're getting?

Comment: You got it. It's not giving me any errors. The views simply do not appear on the cells as they should.

Comment: Have you tried using Xcode's view debugging to see what's being displayed and where?  (Including things that may be offscreen.)

Comment: I did try the view debugging. In the version of the code I want to work, those views are no where to be found, not offscreen or anything. Yet when I add an NSLog to check the coordinates of the cvc, I get values as though the frame is right there, existing, just not adding to the cell.